# Mysql query result inserting an L into records

Tags: python, mysql

I have this query

```
cursor.execute("SELECT product_id FROM search_products_3")
front_db_ids=cursor.fetchall()
front_db_ids=[a for a in front_db_ids]
```

In the database the product_id is an Integer and I have those numbers:
    110033, 110034, 110035

but the result of the query I am getting is

```
[(110033L,), (110034L,), (110035L,)]
```

My question is why do I have this "L" inserted in the records and why the query result is a list of tuples and not a list of single values?

Comment: It would be great, if you mention, where the "cursor" comes from, as there are more libraries serving myslq in Python. Without explicit reference or sample one has to guess, where you got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "L" stands for "long integer".

Your results are long integers, which can be used as any other integer. If you want to print it out, standard Python format function will not put the "L" there.

Regarding tuple: fetchall always returns tuple of values, your case with just one value is also delivered inside of a tuple.

Comment: @user2950162 You are welcome. One secret information: At StackOverflow "thanks" translates to "Upvote the answer you find usefull". Even stronger expression of the same is "accepting the answer". Some people get motivated by that :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! already done! it asks for a 5 min before accepting!